# Virtual machine scale set - Permit inbound traffic on a port for a given ip

Tags: azure-networking

I have a virtual machine scale set and want to permit inbound traffic on a port from a given ip. How to implement the same?

From portal, deployed a NSG and associated it with the virtual network of scale set and added inbound rules, but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a virtual machine scale set and want to permit inbound traffic
>   on a port from a given ip. How to implement the same?

Do you mean you want to add a port to this VMSS and use the new port to route network traffic to vmss instances?

If I understand it correctly, we should **add Load balancer probe and load balancer rules** for the new port.

More information about create a probe, LB rule, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-internet-portal#create-a-probe-lb-rule-and-nat-rules).

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)